# Resize an image in Node.js using jimp and get the path the new image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I'm using jimp to resize an image in node.js, I'm successfully able to degrade the image quality, but a bit confused how to get the path of new image

```
Jimp.read("test.jpg", function (err, test) {
        if (err) throw err;
        test.resize(256, 256)
             .quality(50)                 
             .write("new.jpg"); 
    });
```

Comment: Reading the doc (https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp#writing-to-files-and-buffers) tells me you can specify the absolute path in `write` function

Answer (score 9):

try something like:

```
Jimp.read("test.jpg", function (err, test) {
        if (err) throw err;
        test.resize(256, 256)
             .quality(50)                 
             .write(__dirname + "./new.jpg"); 
    });
```

This should save the file to your project root.

More info on [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your image resizing performance **by 20 times**. Just use another module for image processing. Check this out:

https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

As you can see there, jimp module is the slowest module.

Try sharp or canvas.

Comment: Thank you, Jimp is slowest, ram consumer and looks like out of the game. Add a line of pixel on a simple rotate, I needed to patch the rotate version. Avoid it

Answer (score 0):

I am using `app-root-path` npm to get rootPath:

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');
var imgName = new Date().getTime().toString();
var savePath = appRoot + '/uploads/' + imgName;

Jimp.read("test.jpg", function (err, image) {
    if (err) throw err;
    image.resize(256, 256)
         .quality(50)                 
         .write(savePath);

    // save savePath to database

});
```